# Erro de "Non-static method"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, áudio, byte

Segue abaixo a minha parte do código que está dando esse problema de:
*"Non-static method' write(byte[], int,int)' cannot be refenced from a static context"*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não entendi essa mensagem de erro!

Poderiam me ajudar em relação à isso?

O que ela realmente significa e por quê está aparecendo neste trecho do meu código?

Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa conhecer o que são membros estáticos para entender o porque desse aviso.

Neste caso, o método `write()` só pode ser chamado a partir de uma instância da classe `ByteArrayOutputStream`, ou seja, você precisaria criar um objeto do tipo `ByteArrayOutputStream` e daí chamar o método `write()`.